# Trouble with macros

Tags: windows, batch, script, macros

Recently, at work, the program that we have used for years has drastically changed and all of our old file types are no longer supported. This has left us completely out in the cold as to how we can access our old files without using the older software. With that being said, here is my problem with macros that I'm in need of help:

I need to be able to open a file in a specific program, copy all the text in the file, paste the text into a new notepad document and then save the notepad file with the file's original name as a simple text document. I need to do this to an entire folder (and eventually folders within a folder but that can wait for now).

If I need to clarify anything let me know. Thanks for any help you can give me.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried doing this in powershell?

Using powershell you can loop through every file in a directory and copy/paste all contents to another file named with a _new.txt suffix.
I'll try to find a code for this for you, however I' havnt used powershell in quite a while but its relative simple to learn.

Comment: That'd be great, xeet.

Comment: Sounds more like a job for AutoIt, than for PowerShell, to be honest.